# Ionic 2 component use a variable in a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, angular, google-maps, ionic2

I'm developing a map with google maps for multiple markers. My first step is to display one marker. The marker is also displayed in the center of the map. Now I would like to display the shop name in the marker info box. I get the list of the vendors from my woocommerce api, but I have trouble displaying the name in the let content variable. Here is my component file

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ViewController, NavParams, LoadingController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AppConfig } from '../../app/app-config';
import { SowService } from '../../providers/sow-service';
import { TbarService } from '../../providers/tbar-service';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

declare var google;

@Component({
    selector: 'map-page',
    templateUrl: 'map.html'
})
export class MapPage {

    @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
    map: any;

    vendors: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public appConfig: AppConfig, public geolocation: Geolocation,
        public navParams: NavParams, public sowService: SowService, public tb: TbarService, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
        public alertCtrl: AlertController, public translateService: TranslateService) { }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.translateService.get(['Notice', 'Loading', 'NetWork_Error', 'OK']).subscribe(value => {
            var loadingModal = this.loadingCtrl.create({
                content: value['Loading']
            });
            loadingModal.present();
            this.sowService.getVendorList().then((data) => {
                this.vendors = data;
                loadingModal.dismiss();
            }, (reson) => {
                loadingModal.dismiss();
                this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: value['Notice'],
                    message: value['NetWork_Error'],
                    buttons: [value['OK']]
                });
            });
        });

    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.loadMap();
    }

    loadMap() {

        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

            let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            let mapOptions = {
                center: latLng,
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
            this.map = this.addMarker();

        },(err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    addMarker() {

        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: this.map.getCenter()
        });

        let content = "<h4>" + this.vendor.shop_name + "</h4>";

        this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);

    }

    addInfoWindow(marker, content) {

        let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
            infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
        });

    }
}
```

There you can see let content = "" + this.vendor.shop_name + ""; 
What did I do wrong? When I use vendor.shop_name in the html file the names are listed. I tried to create a list below the map for testing purposes.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>{{ 'Map' | translate }}</ion-title>

    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <div style="width:100%; height:50%" #map="" id="map"></div>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let vendor of vendors" (click)="vendorSelected(vendor)">
        <h2>{{ vendor.shop_name }}</h2>
        <h3 *ngIf="vendor.sow_vendor_geocoding!=''" class='shop-user-text'>
            {{vendor.sow_vendor_geocoding}}
        </h3>
        <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" item-right></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: any suggestions?